# How to simultaneously display values from two lists

Tags: flutter, dart

from the code below , i've got one list where its values are mapped as text into the title of radioListTile , I basically want to iterate over another list where its values will be mapped as text into the subtitle of the radioListTile , how can i go about implementing this -

```
     ...data.List1.split('.').map(
                              (e) => RadioListTile(
                                  title: Text(e),
                                subtitle: //List2 values,

                                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through lists construct a `RadioListTile` and add it into a `List<RadioListTile>`:

```
    final radios = <RadioListTile>[];
    for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
      radios.add(RadioListTile(title: titles[i], sub: subs[i]));
    }
```